# Square of the magnitude

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the square of the magnitude $A(x)$?
Suppose $A(x)=e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}$. Find $|A(x)|^2$

Is it correct to say that 
$|A(x)|^2= e^{mi}-e^{-mi}=2 \cos(m)$

Comment: $|A|^2=A^*A$ Where * is conjugate

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Expand the first term to $e^{\sqrt{\frac m2}}e^{i\sqrt{\frac m2}}$ and use Euler's formula to get the real and imaginary parts. It should be easy to see what the second term is from that.  Multiply the sum by its conjugate to get the absolute square.

Added:  The last term should have a plus sign as two minuses cancel. Now when you multiply by the conjugate you get $\cos^2 \sqrt{\frac m2}(e^{m/2}-2+e^{-m/2})+\sin^2 \sqrt{\frac m2}(e^{m/2}+2+e^{-m/2})$  The outer terms add to $2\cosh e^{m/2}$ and the inner ones to $2(\sin^2\sqrt{\frac m2}-\cos^2 \sqrt{\frac m2})=-2\cos2\sqrt{\frac m2}$.  This is not quite the result you were looking for.

Comment: I expand $ e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}=e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}[\cos \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}+i \sin\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}]-e^{- \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}[\cos \sqrt{\frac{m}{2} - \sin \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}]  $ The real part is $\cos\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}[e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}} -e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}] $ So what should I do after that?

Comment: I can't read the MathJax in your comment.  I tried copying it into my post so I could put dollar signs in various places.  There seems to be a problem I can't find soon after the first equal sign.

Comment: If you edit it into your post, it will render so you can make sure it looks like you want.  I usually put it under the original, marked Added:

Comment: I expand    $e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}(1+i)}=e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}[\cos \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}+i \sin\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}] -e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}[\cos \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}-i \sin\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}]$
$=\cos \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}[e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}]+i \sin\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}[e^{\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}-e^{-\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}}]$ I get stuck here. How can we prove that $|A(x)|^2=2[\cosh \sqrt{2 m}- \cos \sqrt{2 m}]$